# MismatchedInputException - Jackson deserialize

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to read my *.json* file. Is is a `VehicleRepository` class.

```
"{\"vehicles\":[{\"id\":\"9467d079-4502-4dba-9d23-b8506dfc7ef4\",\"plate\":\"ghghghhg\",\"manufacturer\":\"Alfa Romeo\",\"model\":\"hgghgh\",\"color\":\"Amarelo\"}]}"
```

This is the error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `VehicleRepository` (although at least one Creator exists): Cannot construct instance of `VehicleRepository` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 1]

To create the `.json` file I'm using this:

```
repository.vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
repository.vehicles.add(vehicle);           

json = mapper.writeValueAsString(repository);   

ObjectMapper write = new ObjectMapper();
write.writeValue(new File("Database//Vehicles.json"), json);
```

And to read the `.json` file I'm using this:

```
VehicleRepository newRepository = mapper.readValue(new File("Database\\Vehicles.json"), VehicleRepository.class);
```

**And it's in the above line that the error occurs.**

This is my `Vehicle` class:

```
public class Vehicle {

    private String id;
    private String plate;
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private String color;

    public Vehicle() {}

    public Vehicle(String plate, String manufacturer, String model, String color) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.plate = plate;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public Vehicle(String id, String plate, String manufacturer, String model, String color) {
        this.id = id;
        this.plate = plate;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }

    public void setPlate(String plate) {
        this.plate = plate;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

And this is my `VehicleRepository` class:

```
public class VehicleRepository {

    List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public VehicleRepository() {

    }

    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }

    public void setVehicles(List<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are first converting the object to a String and writing that String as JSON to the file.

You can just write the object to the file using:

```
write.writeValue(new File("Vehicles.json"), repository);
```

The result would be this correct json:

```
{"vehicles":[{"id":"9467d079-4502-4dba-9d23-b8506dfc7ef4","plate":"ghghghhg","manufacturer":"Alfa Romeo","model":"hgghgh","color":"Amarelo"}]}
```

This can be readed perfectly with the code you already have:

```
VehicleRepository newRepository = mapper.readValue(new File("Vehicles.json"), VehicleRepository.class);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Great explanation.